# Непонятна логика try-except-end

Tags: delphi

```
procedure TForm1.Edit4KeyPress(Sender: TObject; var Key: Char);
                   begin
if not ( key in [ '0'..'9', #8]) then
begin
Key := #0;
 MessageDlg('Ошибка! В поле ввода могут содержаться только символы 0,1,...,9 и Backspace',mtError,[mbOk],0);
end;
end;
```

Подскажите, как в данной процедуре расставить обработку исключительной ситуации **try..except**? И по какой логике нужно расставлять обработку? Спасибо.

Правка:
вся задача, собственно, состоит в том, чтобы расставить выполнение обработки исключительной ситуации в процедурах, но хочется до этого самому дойти. Но все равно не понятно, как именно и по какой логике расставлять эти обработки в процедуре:

```
TForm1.Button1Click(Sender: TObject); 
var Number,Code:integer; 
begin 
if Edit1.Text<>'' then 
begin 
val(Edit1.Text,Number,Code); 
if Code<>0 then 
begin 
Edit1.SetFocus; 
MessageDlg('Ошибка! В поле ввода должно содержаться только числовое значение целого типа', mtError,[mbOk],0) 
end 
end;
 end;
```

Собственно, все.

Comment: Вообще, здесь нет логики, которая требует try..except. Кстати, код выглядит ужасно.

Answer (score 3):

В вашем куске кода не могут возникнуть исключения. Поэтому и экранировать ничего не нужно. А, вот для вывода ошибки, лучше воспользоваться стандартными средствами языка:

```
procedure TForm1.Edit4KeyPress(Sender: TObject; var Key: Char);
begin
  if not ( key in [ '0'..'9', #8]) then
  begin
    Key := #0;
    raise Exception.Create('Ошибка! В поле ввода могут содержаться только символы 0,1,...,9 и Backspace');
  end;
end;
```

Смысл в том, что для создания пользовательского исключения не нужны дополнительные библиотеки, такие как `Dialogs` для функции `MessageDlg()`. А кастомизировать вывод исключений можно через компонент `ApplicationEvent` и его событие `OnException`.

Comment: А вот теперь можно это оборачивать в `try...except`. Паттерн *подбрасывание исключения* :-)

Comment: Конкретно в этом случае нет смысла. А вот во многих других может быть кстати.

Comment: Смысл вывода ошибки на исключение понятен. 
А в данном куске кода обработку исключения можно сделать так же, как вы привели? (не знаю как в комментариях использовать кодировку, извините уж):

procedure TForm1.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
var Number,Code:integer;
begin
  if Edit1.Text<>'' then
       begin
          val(Edit1.Text,Number,Code);
          if Code<>0 then
            begin
              Edit1.SetFocus;
MessageDlg('Ошибка! В поле ввода должно содержаться только числовое значение целого типа', mtError,[mbOk],0)
            end
       end;
        end;

Comment: @tkoff, редактируйте вопрос. Если бы вы сразу раскрыли тайну задачи, то и ответ бы уже давно имели.

Answer (score 1):

`try.. except.. end` будет уместен в твоей ситуации, если на событие `KeyPress` объекта `Edit1` не накладывать оброботчик типа `Edit4KeyPress`. Тогда, например, можно cделать такое:

```
TForm1.Button1Click(Sender: TObject); 
var Number:integer; 
 begin 
  try
   if Edit1.Text<>'' then 
    begin 
    Number:=StrToInt(Edit1.Text); 
    ... //Юзаем Number на своё усмотрение 
   end;
  except 
   Edit1.SetFocus; 
   MessageDlg('Ошибка! В поле ввода должно содержаться только числовое значение целого типа', mtError,[mbOk],0) 
  end; 
 end;
end;
```